# How to make LSD:line detector not to use Gauss (not sample given image)?

Tags: c++, opencv, line, detection

I want to search lines on really small (10x10 or smaller) images. I want to use [LSD line detector](http://www.ipol.im/pub/algo/gjmr_line_segment_detector/) because it is super fast. I downloaded there C code and have a sample on how to use it. But I do not get how to make it not to perform Gauss and such to lower data qualyty.

BTW I use suc function to perform LSD on open CV image:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "LSD.h"

using namespace std;
int linesFoundOnPicture;
    void ProcessLSD(IplImage* source)
    {
        int w = source->width;
        int h = source->height;
        image_double lsdImage;
        ntuple_list lsdOut;
        unsigned int x,y,i,j;
        lsdImage = new_image_double(w,h);


        for(x=0;x<w;x++){
            for(y=0;y<h;y++){
                double RealColor = cvGetReal2D(source, y, x);
                lsdImage->data[ x + y * lsdImage->xsize ] = RealColor;/* image(x,y) */
            cout << RealColor << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }cout << endl;

        lsdOut = lsd(lsdImage);

    if (lsdOut->size == 0)
    {
        cout << "0 0 0 0";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << lsdOut->values[ 0 * lsdOut->dim + 0 ] << " " <<  lsdOut->values[ 0 * lsdOut->dim + 1] << " ";
        cout << lsdOut->values[ 0 * lsdOut->dim + 2 ] << " " << lsdOut->values[ 0 * lsdOut->dim + 3 ] << " ";
        linesFoundOnPicture = linesFoundOnPicture +1;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //  cvReleaseImage(&source);
        free_image_double(lsdImage);
        free_ntuple_list(lsdOut);
    }
```

So can any one please help me to master LSD?)

Seems like there is somethihg like 3 functions that provide lists with lines in LSD.h...

```
ntuple_list LineSegmentDetection( image_double image, double scale,
    double sigma_scale, double quant,
    double ang_th, double eps, double density_th,
    int n_bins, double max_grad,
    image_int * region );

ntuple_list lsd_scale(image_double image, double scale);

ntuple_list lsd(image_double image);
```

Looks like best option of understanding LSD params [is](http://blog.inspirit.ru/wp-content/uploads/aslsd/main.swf) [this flash lsd port where you can play with values](http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/wiki/ASLSD) (seems to me of first of that 3 lsd functions)

Comment: and image you feed LSD must be B/W so use something like `IplImage *source = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1); cvCvtColor(destination,source,CV_RGB2GRAY);`

Comment: [LSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysergic_acid_diethylamide)? maybe you are better off asking in biochemical.stackexchange.com? (Just kidding)

Comment: Yep.. actually flash app ( http://blog.inspirit.ru/wp-content/uploads/aslsd/main.swf )was very helpful - I now get all params exept  image_int * region.